# Zoom in animation from particular position - android

Tags: android, android-animation

In my app, I have 4 buttons in my activity (See screenshot). I want to open activities when the button is clicked but with zoom in animation. 
[This](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html) is what I want to achieve! In the given link (docs) the zoom animation is taking place on `ImageViews` but I want it on activities.
 Please help me achieve it! Thanks!

Here is my activity:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this SO answer and question.. he has already done ur requirement along with reverse animation
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057925/zoom-out-animation-android