# Zoom out animation - Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using zoom in animation for a view in my app. When the user clicks on a button the next activity zooms in from that button. [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXqvK5YT5kQ) is what I have achieved using the code give below.

Since the in the video mentioned above, the code that was shown only worked for jellybean and above I had to use the code given below.

**Next_Activity.java** (The activity with zoom in animation)

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); // Bundle passed from previous activity to this activity

    x = b.getInt("X");              //b is button in previous activity
    y = b.getInt("Y");              //b is button in previous activity
    xh = b.getInt("XH");            //b is button in previous activity
    yh = b.getInt("YH");            //b is button in previous activity

    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    width = display.getWidth();
    height = display.getHeight();


    Animation scale = new ScaleAnimation( (float)xh/width, 1f, (float)yh/height , 1f, x, y);

    Animation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(.75f, 1f);

    set.addAnimation(scale);
    set.addAnimation(alpha);

    set.setDuration(300);

    main.startAnimation(set);            //main is rootLayout of this activity
```

**Main_Activity**(The Activity with button)

```
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   int[] xy = new int[2];

   button.getLocationOnScreen(xy);

   bundle.putInt("X", xy[0] + (b.getWidth() / 2));
   bundle.putInt("Y", xy[1] + (b.getHeight() / 2));
   bundle.putInt("XH", b.getWidth());
   bundle.putInt("YH", b.getHeight());

   Intent startnextactivity = new Intent(Table_main.this,Next_Activity.class);
   startnextactivity.putExtras(bb);
   startActivity(startnextactivity);
```

Now, my question is how do I reverse this animation? I mean when I click on the button, the activity zooms in from that button. So how do I zoom out the activity to the same button when the back button is pressed?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
Animation scale = new ScaleAnimation( (float)xh/width, 1f, (float)yh/height , 1f, x, y);
// What is the zoom out animation of the above line??
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    x = b.getInt("X");
    y = b.getInt("Y");
    xh = b.getInt("XH");
    yh = b.getInt("YH");
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
    width = display.getWidth();
    height = display.getHeight();
    Animation scale = new ScaleAnimation((1f, (float) xh/width, 1f, (flaot) yh/height, x, y);
    Animation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(.75f, 1f);
    set.addAnimation(scale);
    set.addAnimation(alpha);
    set.setDuration(300);
    main.startAnimation(set);   
}
```

Comment: I could figure that out myself. But How do I reverse the zoom in animation? Can you please tell me the zoom out animation of this line
`Animation scale = new ScaleAnimation( (float)xh/width, 1f, (float)yh/height , 1f, x, y);`

Comment: @DroidFan I'm afraid I don't know what the six arguments in the `ScaleAnimation` constructor refer to. If I did, I might be able to help you, but as of now, they are arbitrary numbers to me.

Comment: Please have a look at the code again. I have posted both the activities and what the arguments refer to. What I was not able to do is to reverse the animation line . Thanks!

Comment: I found the constructor to be `ScaleAnimation(float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY, float pivotX, float pivotY)` from the Android Developers website. Judging by this, my guess would be to swap the `fromX`/`fromY` with the `toX`/`toY` values, respectively. It would then look like `Animation scale = new ScaleAnimation((1f, (float) xh/width, 1f, (flaot) yh/height, x, y);`